# php 7.2 constant error appear after defined

Tags: php, php-7.2

I have this error appear after to defined the constant

how to resolve ?

> Warning: Use of undefined constant MODULE_HEADER_BREADCRUMP_STATUS - assumed 'MODULE_HEADER_BREADCRUMP_STATUS' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/clients/client1/web13/web/boutique/sources/template/Default/files/breadcrumb.php on line 22

my line

```
  if (defined(MODULE_HEADER_BREADCRUMP_STATUS)) {
    if (MODULE_HEADER_BREADCRUMP_STATUS != 'True' || empty(MODULE_HEADER_BREADCRUMP_TITLE) ) {...
    }
  }
```

Comment: didn't you post something similar earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236765/undefined-constant-error-in-php-7-2 - qualifies as a repost, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When checking to see if a constant is defined, add quotes around it:

```
if(defined("MODULE_HEADER_BREADCRUMP_STATUS"))
```

Comment: Man … the quotes totally got me :D +1