# How guess php version by static analysis of code

Tags: php, phalcon

How to "guess" php version by looking at code?

Suppose you're handed a zip file containing php code for an application.
Are there any telltale signs about which version (5.x, 7.1, 7.3,etc )
the original author was working with?

My issue is, I suspect I'm running an incorrect php version for my (phalcon) application, my users can't log in. I see in logs

> "PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant success - assumed 'success' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"

and

> Uncaught Error: Class 'View' not found in ....

Comment: No - you would have to infer this from the featureset used within the code. Even then you'd have no way of being sure what version the author was using with, merely which *minimum* version he or she was using. If your server has multi-version PHP support, the best thing would be to trial-and-error increment PHP version until it works, work it out that way.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is not possible. You can inspect the set of features the original author used and try to identify a minimal version. When you find removed features you can also find a maximum version.

According to your warning message I assume you are using PHP 7.2 right now?!
The author probably developed this with a lower version (5.x) or has disabled warnings.

Maybe have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48236808/6237870) for more info about your warning message.

However, the warnings and errors you get are not really version related but seem to result from missing files and / or bad programming. 
You should try to make it work with Version 7.2+ instead of choosing the version matching the developers version. Have a look at PHP versions [here](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).